# Configure HTTP Proxy for SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, proxy

I have the task to download RSS feed from location outside our company's network via SSIS. I do this using the simple script task:

```
public bool DownloadFeed()
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        web.DownloadFile(@"http://bullshit.com/feeds/something.xml", @"c:\exchange\something.xml");
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download XML", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, string.Empty, 0);
        return false; 
    }
    finally {
        web.Dispose();
    }
```

From Visual Studion at my PC it works normally. But when I deploy dtsx package to MS SQL Server and create job - the job fails with the message

```
Download Feed:Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at ST_7e86d0b503664f0abba3beedf3d81f00.ScriptMain.DownloadFeed()
```

The job runs under service AD account that has access to Internet, and when I connect to the server via mstsc under that account I can open the feed using web browser.

I think the reason is that all Internet access in our company is via proxy server. The proxy settings are set up correctly in Internet options. But I guess the SQL Server agent that starts job doesn't use that settings and tries to download the file bypassing the proxy server. I've asked our admins to allow that server to access Internet directly, without proxy, but it contradicts with our information security policy.

Could you please advice how to set up proxy server at SQL to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a non-authenticated proxy this should do:

```
public bool DownloadFeed()
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("[proxy address]", [proxy port]);
    web.Proxy = proxy;
    try
    {
```

You should be able to grab the value from IE, Internet options -> Connection -> Lan Settings, or just from admins.

Comment: Thank you! But our proxy requires authentication. A did like this: WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxy:port", true, bypassList, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials); but it return an error "authorization needed"

Comment: I added web.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; it works if I start the job manually, but if it's triggered by schedule - it fails with message Download Feed:Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at ST_7e86d0b503664f0abba3beedf3d81f00.ScriptMain.DownloadFeed()

Comment: oh man, that's looks closer but not quite.   temporary short term testing to sanity check: proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domainuser", "domainpassword");
Next would be to try DefaultNetworkCredentials again + SQL Server -> Security -> Credential (of sanity check), SQL Agent Proxies -> SSIS Package Execution -> Proxies, Job's Run As (Proxy)

Comment: i said DefaultNetworkCredentials, should have been DefaultWebProxy after sanity check.